# LoadLibrary('user32.dll') returns 14007

Tags: c++, crash, user32

If I try to use the LoadLibrary to load User32.dll the function returns error 14007 (ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND). This is the code I use:

```
SetLastError(0); //To make sure there are no previous errors.
HINSTANCE hUserModule = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
if (hUserModule == NULL) { //Checking if hUserModule is NULL
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Fatal error", "", 16);
    ExitProcess(0);
} //hUserModule is not NULL
printf("%d\n", GetLastError()); //14007
DWORD paMessageBoxA = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(hUserModule, "MessageBoxA");
__MessageBoxA MsgBox = (__MessageBoxA)paMessageBoxA; //typedef int(__stdcall *__MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
MsgBox(NULL, "", "", 64); //Application crahses
```

So the hUserModule is not NULL, but also not valid. Why is this?

EDIT: GetModuleHandle also doesn't work

Comment: Generally you should check the error code (as returned by `GetLastError`) *only* if a function failed. Otherwise you might get false positives.

Comment: As for your crash, did you check that `GetProcAddress` didn't fail?

Comment: Lastly, and totally unrelated to your problem, but don't have your own symbols starting with double underscore. Those are reserved by the "implementation" (compiler and standard library) in all scopes. [See this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information.

Comment: Nothing is stopping `LoadLibrary` from using other functions (internally) which may call `SetLastError`.  When value from `GetLastError` is valid is described in the documentation.

Comment: I did and it returned error code 0

Comment: By the way (and this is *very* related to your problem), are you on a 64-bit system? `DWORD` is defined as `long` which using the Visual C++ compiler is 32 bits. On a 64 bit system addresses (like the ones returned by [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx)) are 64 bits, and storing it in a 32 bit variable can truncate the address.

Comment: Yes I am using a 64 bit system and its being compiled in a 64 bit application

Comment: You are truncating the result from `GetProcAddress`.  `FARPROC` is bigger than `DWORD` on 64 bit systems see the definition of `GetProcAddress`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Farproc worked. I didn't know that FARPROC is required when using function addresses on 64 bit machines / applications

Comment: Why are you doing this? Instead of linking to the dynamic library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 64-bit system addresses are 64 bits wide. The `DWORD` type is "A 32-bit unsigned integer" (quoted from [this MSDN type reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)).

That means you *truncate* the address you receive from [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) making it invalid.

The solution is to use a proper pointer type, casting to that type instead of to `DWORD`. Perhaps something like

```
__MessageBoxA MsgBox = (__MessageBoxA) GetProcAddress(hUserModule, "MessageBoxA");
```

(Assuming `__MessageBoxA` *is* a proper pointer.)